# dijit.byId() returns undefined even in dojo.addOnLoad()

Tags: javascript, undefined, dojo

i have recently started to work in dojo.
dijit.byId() returns undefined even if i put this call inside dojo.onLoad().

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
dojo.require("dijit.form.Select");
function myhandler(ev)
{
    var mydiv = dojo.byId('mydivid');
    if (ev == 'Disable') {
        mydiv.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        mydiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
function regHandler()
{
    var item = dijit.byId("myState");
    alert(item);//shows undefined
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId("myState"), 'onChange', myhandler);
}
dojo.addOnLoad(regHandler);
</script>

<select input class="dialogInputElement" dojoAttachPoint="myState" dojoType=dijit.form.Select name="myState" id="myState" value='Enable' style="margin-bottom:5px">
<option value="Enable">Enable</option>
<option value="Disable">Disable</option>
</select>
```

it works fine if i delay  dijit.byId() call with setTimeout().
dojo version is 1.4.2
Any solution or workaround will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe Dojo's onLoad event guarantees that dijits have been parsed and instantiated (and hence are available to `dijit.byId`). Do you have `parseOnLoad: true` in your dojoConfig? What happens if you add `dojo.parser.parse();` to your `regHandler` (before the rest of its code)?

Answer (score 5):

If this is verbatim from your code, it looks like you are missing double-quotes from around your `dojoType` declaration. If your input is never declared as a dijit widget, it will never be retrievable by `dijit.byId()`.

If you want a more general node selector, use `dojo.byId()` instead, it will select any node with an id, not just dijit widgets.

Comment: Always remember to put double queotes around HTML attributes.

Comment: @Ryan i tried with quotes also, it did not make any difference. dojo.byId(), i believe, returns html element. but can i use it to call dojo.connect()?

Comment: @missingno with or without quotes, it work if i add a delay, like below:    `function regHandler()
    {
        var item = dijit.byId("myState");
        alert(item);//shows undefined
        dojo.connect(dijit.byId("myState"), 'onChange', myhandler);
    }
    function myshim()
    {
        setTimeout("regHandler()", 1000);
    }
dojo.addOnLoad(myshim);` but i want it to work without delay.

Comment: @user469635 Based on the examples [here](http://davidwalsh.name/dojo-connect) and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-dojoconnect/?ca=drs-), it is definitely possible to use the value returned by `dojo.byId` as the first argument(target) for `dojo.connect()`.

Comment: @Ryan dojo.byId is used When connecting events to simple DOM elements. for digit elements dijit.byId is required.

Comment: @ryan sorry. dojo.byid is can also be used in dojo.connect(). could not vote you up. new user, i do not have enough reputation.

Comment: replacing dijit.byId with dojo.byId is not returning undefined but connect is not working. [http://jsfiddle.net/ranjeetsih/kdvS4/3/]

Comment: if you are using domNodes for `connect` (`dojo.byId()`) rather than dijit widgets (`dijit.byId()`), you will be connecting to a different event.  `onChange` is a dijit specific event.  `onchange` is the generic javascript event you would want to connect to (note the capitalization).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding  the attribute djConfig="parseOnLoad: true" to the dojo configuration?

When you include the dojo.js library file you can set the attribute like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
</script>
```

In my tests, this seems to solve the problem. In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sf8Lu/) note if you remove the djconfig tag attribute (on the left nav bar) and run it, you get the behavior you are describing.

Comment: Duh! How could I have forgotten this? Of course, you have to also tell dojo to parse your augmented HTML.